# Responsive design: Will this Javascript cause the browser to download both images

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

I have a question regarding responsive design and images.

Will this javascript cause the browser to load both the "small.jpg" and the "big.jpg"?

```
if (condition1) {
    //with jQuery im setting the source for the img tag
    $(this).attr('src',  'small.jpg');

} else if (condition2) {
    //with jQuery im setting the source for the img tag  
    $(this).attr('src',  'big.jpg');
}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: So did you try?what is the result?

Comment: I always thought responsive design is more about css and media queries - maybe you could look into those for choosing the right image sizes?

Comment: This will not load both images. If first condition is met, the second condition will not get a chance thanks to the `else if`.

Comment: if you have problems with if else statements, i wouldn't be concerned with responsive design

Comment: What `src` has the `<img>` initially in the HTML markup? Your script might neither load `small.jpg` nor `big.jpg` if both conditions fail.

Comment: Thanks for the help - Just wanted to be sure. I have  been testing and studing alternatives but using Javascript fills my need for now

[link]http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

[link]http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not load both images. If first condition is met, the second condition will not get a chance thanks to the `else if`.

Comment: Thanks for the help - Just wanted to be sure. I have  been testing and studing alternatives but using Javascript fills my need for now

[link]http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

[link]http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the conditions, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Please give us an example with conditions where both codes will run.